# Pug syntax highlighting wont work after inserting markdown code in vim editor

Tags: vim, pug, markdown

I am inserting markdown code in my pug file to put a simple paragraph with some text then continue with jade/pug code.

However when I'm done with markdown code I can't delimit ( stop ) markdown syntax with indentations. Everything is still highlighted as markdown in my vim editor but when I save it compiles fine with gulp-pug.

This is annoying because after markdown code I don't get pug syntax highlighting.

[image: using pug now and problem still]

I'm using vim version : 7.4 ( vim-nox )
I also have vim-markdown and vim-pug ( earlier called: vim-jade ) plugins installed.

Comment: Are you working on `.jade` or `.pug` file. For me `vim-pug` was working fine with `.pug`  files

Comment: Ah i'm using vim-pug and .pug extension too. I've updated the question it now read better. @meain

Comment: Oops. I was not able to reproduce your issue. It was working fine for me.

Comment: @meain it's alright. I've learned to live with it for I put any markdown content in it's own file then include it whenever i need it. This works well with `.md and .svg` files.